# Unable to establish relationship in featuretools

Tags: featuretools

I am having some problems when using this:
Several of my entities have "id" and "time", and of course there are some other records.

Since it records the activity data for each id every day, my id is not unique in a table. I want to establish a relationship by id, but it doesn't seem to work. I want to know if featuretools supports such a function.

```
Class featuretools.Relationship(parent_variable, child_variable)
```

Does its `parent_variable` and `child_variable` only accept columns with unique values?

Or can I use a single entity to create some `agg_primitives` parameters as mentioned in the official documentation below？

```
In [3]: feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
   ...:                                       target_entity="customers",
   ...:                                       agg_primitives=["mean","max", "min", "std", "skew"],
   ...:                                       trans_primitives=["time_since_previous"])
```

I used this for the first time and I was confused.

Comment: can you share a sample of the table of data you have? with that, we can more easily give advice. thanks!

Comment: `featuretools` relationships must be "one-to-many", so `parent_id` must be unique.